# DRF: What's the difference between Field and Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

We can use serializer as a field inside another serializer..

Wonder why there's a Field class and Serializer class in DRF?

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

example serializer is taken from the doc https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

As you can see, `UserSerializer` is much like a `Field` . 
I'm just curious why they have serializer and field class separately..

Comment: can you add more detail for your question? Like anything example.

Comment: @NgocPham added.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serilaizer is infact a field in DRF. Serializers can be nested and that is why it can be used as a field in other serializers. And yes, if you check the source code, the `BaseSerializer` is a subclass of `Field` as the serializer is just a special case of a field.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

In `django rest framwork`, you can think `Serializer` like a mask. It cover your origin data and change it to anything you want. Like format your `json` data , or validate your input data have correct format or not.

In your example,

```
content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

`Comment` have 2 direct field type `CharField` and `DateTimeField`.

```
user = UserSerializer()
```

`Comment` have field type is  `UserSerializer`. This is different `Serializer`, and `django` know your `CommentSerializer` will have relationship with `UserSerializer`. And anything define in `UserSerializer` will use in here, for format json output or validate. And with define this `nested objects`, your output json will have more data like

`'user': {'email': 'foobar', 'username': 'doe'}`

And if you want create `Comment` with one `user`, you must pass all validate define in `UserSerializer`.

Conclude: in this example

- `Field class` use for direct field.
- `Serializer class` for    relationship with other class